# Div as height as possible (100% stretch)

Tags: html, css

I have this layout:

```
banner
menu
-----
main    ||
content ||
```

I need the banner+menu always visible, the site is for mobile devices, so only vertical scrolling on "main content". But I have no idea how to achieve this. I set 100% to body/html, still no fun. No matter how long the "main content" I want to scroll only this.

Comment: `div#banner, div#menu {position: fixed;}`

Answer (score 2):

Set the banner/menu as `position: fixed` in your CSS. Learn more here: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Comment: but then the two div hide themselves

Comment: Check out the article - I think you need to read up on the basics of CSS positioning.

Comment: but it cant be that hard - its like I set a fixed height to the "main content". If I do, everything is perfect - but I cant know the height...

Comment: You don't need to set the height on body/html at all. You just need to figure out the sizing of the banner and menu, set them to fixed, attach them to the top and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

ok, its OK for doing that:

```
<body style="margin: 0px;">

<div style="position: relative; background-color: green; height: 100px;">fixed</div>
<div style="position: absolute; background-color: red; top: 100px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; ">abs</div>

</body>
```

but that 100px height is changing, not fixed....

Comment: or even better:     <div style="position: fixed; overflow: scroll; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; top: 100px; background: red;">a<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1</div>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 100px; background-color: yellowgreen;">fixed</div>